# How can i print list of dict values, one value in list for each key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict of this form...

```
d={'s1':{'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6]},'s2':{'d':[77,88,99],'e':[666,333,444]}}
```

so i want to print in this format

```
s1
a, 1
b,4
s1

s1
a,2
b,5
s1

s1
a,3
b,6
s1

s2
d,77
e,666
s2

s2
d,88
e,333
s2

s2
d,99
e,444
s2
```

i tried in this method

```
for k,v in d.items():
    print k
    for key,val in v.items():
        print key,val[0] # But this v[0] should change and key also should changthat i am not getting for same loop
    print k
```

so i have to print main key for all values, where values is one more dict,in that dict each time i should print key for each list item
can anyone help me thanks in  advance

Comment: What did you try? Did you try anything at all?

Comment: Is this data structure correct?

Comment: That is not a `dict`. I assume it's supposed to be this so I will edit it: `d={'s1':{'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6]},'s2':{'d':[77,88,99],'e':[666,333,444]}}`

Comment: Does the order of the output matter?

Comment: @MarkByers i tried by iterating over items of dict but at a time it prints keys and values but i want in this format.......

Comment: @jamylak thanks for correcting , can u help now

Comment: This is one of those questions where if the OP hasn't posted an effort, its just too much work to do it for them and the purpose hasn't been stated so we don't care enough to try. Nutshell: Too obscure, and no effort posted.

Comment: I guess if you want this particular format then you should try some other data-structure.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: I concur. The amount of effort required to simply reformat this structure suggests that it should be re-examined in the first place. What is it being used for? Is this kind of formatting a comment operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
>>> d={'s1':{'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6]},'s2':{'d':[77,88,99],'e':[666,333,444]}}
>>> for k in sorted(d.keys()):
...   v = d[k]
...   for i in xrange(len(v.values()[0])):
...     print k
...     for k2 in sorted(v.keys()):
...       v2 = v[k2]
...       print "%s,%d" % (k2, v2[i])
...     print "%s\n" % k
...
```

When I ran this it printed:

```
s1
a,1
b,4
s1

s1
a,2
b,5
s1

s1
a,3
b,6
s1

s2
d,77
e,666
s2

s2
d,88
e,333
s2

s2
d,99
e,444
s2
```

Comment: Thats probably the best you can get, since you have to assume the length of all the lists will be equal and take the first length.

Comment: @srgerg thanks ur code is working fine, can u explain what ur code is doing with comments....... thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> from itertools import product, starmap
>>> d={'s1':{'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6]},'s2':{'d':[77,88,99],'e':[666,333,444]}}
>>> for k,v in sorted(d.items()): # use d.iteritems for py2
        for x,y in zip(*starmap(product,sorted(v.items()))):
            print k
            print '{0},{1}'.format(*x)
            print '{0},{1}'.format(*y)
            print k
            print


s1
a,1
b,4
s1

s1
a,2
b,5
s1

s1
a,3
b,6
s1

s2
d,77
e,666
s2

s2
d,88
e,333
s2

s2
d,99
e,444
s2
```

**Explanation**

It gets the value pairs with the key of each list in the dictionary so

```
{'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6]}
```

is changed into

```
[(('a', 1), ('b', 4)), (('a', 2), ('b', 5)), (('a', 3), ('b', 6))]
```

Here is how that is done:

The first line goes through each key and value in `d`. These have to be sorted so i can iterate through in ascending order since dictionaries do not have an order.

The value for the key is a dictionary like the one below, it is sorted in tuples of key,value pairs.

```
d = {'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6]}
>>> sorted(d.items())
[('a', [1, 2, 3]), ('b', [4, 5, 6])]
```

Then `product` is used to get the key paired with every value.

```
>>> [product(*x) for x in sorted(d.items())]
# iterates through [('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('a', 3)], [('b', 4), ('b', 5), ('b', 6)]
```

This can be written more simply using `starmap`, which was built like `map` although the arguments for the function(in this case `product`) come in tuples. See [doc](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap)

```
>>> starmap(product,sorted(d.items()))
# iterates through [('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('a', 3)], [('b', 4), ('b', 5), ('b', 6)]
```

Then the lists are `zippped` together.

```
>>> zip(*starmap(product,sorted(d.items())))
[(('a', 1), ('b', 4)), (('a', 2), ('b', 5)), (('a', 3), ('b', 6))]
```